# .bag file error by Hokuyo laser scanner

Tags: ros, bagfile, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. I tried to use " rosbag record -O mylaserdata /base_scan /tf " to record the distance data. But after I finish the recording, there is no message recorded to the ".bag" file. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Is it necessary to set "base_scan" for my laser sensor first? If yes, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173608/.bag-file-error-by-hokuyo-laser-scanner/) by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone needs to send messages on the topics you record. If rostopic echo /base_scan gives you something that should also be in the bag.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0